# Liquid checking props from other includes?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Let's say I have two files, `button.html` and `toggle.html`. For this example, button is irrelevant, but toggle isn't. This is the code for toggle:

```
{% if include.value %}
    {% assign addonclass = 'addon-class' %}
{% endif %}
<div class="toggle {{addonclass}}">
    Some content
</div>
```

Which makes sense right, I want to add a class to that div if whenver I do

`{% include toggle.html value = "somevalue" %}`

Here's the kicker though. On it's own, that works just fine, however, if I on a page I do the following:

```
{% include button.html value = "some value" %}
{% include toggle.html %}
```

The if statement inside toggle will be true, however, it will not output`{{value}}`, it'll just be empty. What the hell? Shouldn't every 'component' mind it's own props, rather than all the props defined everywhere? I understand I have to do something like:

`{% assign labelclass = '' %}`

But why? Why can I pass props to components, if they get passed to all components called? I'm running this with Jekyll btw, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this behavior but all I can get is an `include.value => nil` from inside *toggle*. It can be interesting to see your code. Any repository url ?

Comment: I could clone that part somewhere I guess, but that's what I get as well. `include.value` is empty inside `toggle.html`, however, any condition checking if it's set is true lol. I'll setup the repo someplace